# Local linearity definition of derivative of multivariable function

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

[image]

This is an alternate definition of a derivative of a function from R^2 to R. How do we go from this definition to the old definition or show they are equivalent?

Also, is this actually a better definition of the derivative? If so, why don't we do this for single variable calculus?

Comment: What "old definition" are you referring to?

Comment: f(x+h)-f(x)/h as h approaches 0

Comment: This is the definition of the derivative of a function from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^1$.  The "old definition" you refer to is the is the definition of the derivative of a function from $\mathbb{R}^1$ to $\mathbb{R}^1$.  Two different things.

Answer (score 0):

The "old definition" does not work for functions from $\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$. Because the Newton quotient
$$
\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}
$$
does not make sense when the numerator $h$ is a vector in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

An equivalent way to write (3.2) in your post is
$$
f(x+h)=f(x)+\ell h+r(h)
$$
where
$$
\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{|r(h)|}{\|h\|}=0\;.
$$

Comment: just curious, but is there actually a method to calculate THE derivative of a multivariable function? I do not mean the partial derivatives or the gradient, but the actually derivative according to the definition above.

Comment: @William: Yes. But that's another question. You can certainly ask another one. I would be glad to answer it if you post another question. But we should solve this one first.